# What are the differences between Crawler impact rules and crawl rules in  SharePoint 2010 search?

Tags: search

What are the differences between Crawler impact rules and crawl rules in  SharePoint 2010 search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crawl rules define the "what". You can include/exclude the content you want to crawl. What urls, pages, documents, images etc.

Crawler impact rules defined the "how" or "when". You can control how often the crawl service will request content. So for example, if you only have one server, you could defined impact rules to reduce load on your servers. If you have dedicated crawl/index servers you can request content more frequently instead.

Comment: crawler impact rules are used to define how many simultaneous request can be used and the delay between the requests.