# Crawl Impact rule vs Crawl rule, Exam question 70 - 667

Tags: 2010, search, crawl-rules, certification, 70-667

Can someone confirm if am right for this question as I tried two practising exams and they both are giving me "Wrong answers"

> You have a sharepoint server 2010 sp1 server farm.
>
> You have a front-end Web server and an application server.
>
> You discover that when the application server indexes content, it
> takes a long time for the front-end web server to respond to the user
> requests.
>
> You need to reduce the number of items that the application server can
> index simultaneously.
>
> The solution must ensure that all content is indexed.
>
> what should you configure?
>
> 1. Crawler impact rules
> 2. crawl rules
> 3. host distribution rules
> 4. search scopes

Now claimed answer is number 2 crawl rules, but in central admin setting comes under crawl impact rule,

[image]

Also if someone highlight me what host distribution rules are other then we use them when we have more then 1 crawler databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think answer no. 1. Crawler Impact rules is correct, explained [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/what-are-the-differences-between-crawler-impact-rules-and-crawl-rules-in-sharep).

More about [Crawl rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792871.aspx) on Technet

More about [Crawler impact rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc179340%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on Technet

[Edited]

Host distribution rules are used to associate a host with a specific crawl database. When you add a host and apply, if the host is already distributed to a crawl store, the crawler will be paused and the content will be physically moved and assigned to the crawl DB you select after selecting Redistribute Now button below. This is a resource intensive operation.

Comment: Thanks but Sorry as its not answering my question and am not really a big fan of links as I already been through them before I asked question :).

Comment: now that's what I wanted to know, cheers

Comment: Try to find answers for your exam in this book for example (in preview) http://books.google.cz/books?id=AB1U4LYIvPoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: or this one http://books.google.cz/books?id=TZ9ci3fGokYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false sorry for new comment, it tooks me a while when I found it and the 5 minutes limit for edit is gone.